# Spinning gears css not working in IE

Tags: html, css

I got some css for rotating gears and so far they work great in Firefox but do not work in IE. Can anyone provide a fix to this problem.

Here is my html to reference the classes:

```
<div class="gear" id="gear1"></div>
<div class="gear" id="gear2"></div>
<div class="gear" id="gear3"></div>
<div class="gear" id="gear4"></div>
<div class="gear" id="gear5"></div>
<div class="gear" id="gear6"></div>
<div class="gear" id="gear7"></div>
```

Here is my css:

```
/* CSS3 keyframes */
@-webkit-keyframes ckw {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes ckw {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cckw {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }

    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes cckw {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }

    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}

@keyframes cckw {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }

    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}

/* gears */
.gear {
    float: none;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-direction: normal;
    -o-animation-direction: normal;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0;
    -o-animation-delay: 0;
    -moz-animation-play-state: running;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -o-animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
    animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
    animation-delay: 0;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
    -o-animation-play-state: running;
    animation-play-state: running;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#gear1 {
    background: url('g1.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    height: 85px;
    left: 31px;
    top: 45px;
    width: 85px;
    -moz-animation-name: ckw;
    -moz-animation-duration: 10s;
    -webkit-animation-name: ckw;
    -o-animation-name: ckw;
    animation-name: ckw;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
    -o-animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-duration: 10s;
}

#gear2 {
    background: url('g2.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    height: 125px;
    left: 105px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 125px;
    -moz-animation-name: cckw;
    -moz-animation-duration: 16.84s;
    -webkit-animation-name: cckw;
    -o-animation-name: cckw;
    animation-name: cckw;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 16.84s;
    -o-animation-duration: 16.84s;
    animation-duration: 16.84s;
}

#gear3 {
    background: url('g3.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    height: 103px;
    left: 149px;
    top: 118px;
    width: 103px;
    -moz-animation-name: ckw;
    -moz-animation-duration: 13.5s;
    -webkit-animation-name: ckw;
    -o-animation-name: ckw;
    animation-name: ckw;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 13.5s;
    -o-animation-duration: 13.5s;
    animation-duration: 13.5s;
}

#gear4 {
    background: url('g4.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    height: 144px;
    left: 46px;
    top: 173px;
    width: 144px;
    -moz-animation-name: cckw;
    -moz-animation-duration: 20.2s;
    -webkit-animation-name: cckw;
    -o-animation-name: cckw;
    animation-name: cckw;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 20.2s;
    -o-animation-duration: 20.2s;
    animation-duration: 20.2s;
}

#gear5 {
    background: url('g1.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    height: 85px;
    left: 127px;
    top: 292px;
    width: 85px;
    -moz-animation-name: ckw;
    -moz-animation-duration: 10s;
    -webkit-animation-name: ckw;
    -o-animation-name: ckw;
    animation-name: ckw;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
    -o-animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-duration: 10s;
}

#gear6 {
    background: url('g2.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    height: 125px;
    left: 200px;
    top: 283px;
    width: 125px;
    -moz-animation-name: cckw;
    -moz-animation-duration: 16.84s;
    -webkit-animation-name: cckw;
    -o-animation-name: cckw;
    animation-name: cckw;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 16.84s;
    -o-animation-duration: 16.84s;
    animation-duration: 16.84s;
}

#gear7 {
    background: url('g3.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    height: 103px;
    left: 277px;
    top: 217px;
    width: 103px;
    -moz-animation-name: ckw;
    -moz-animation-duration: 13.5s;
    -webkit-animation-name: ckw;
    -o-animation-name: ckw;
    animation-name: ckw;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 13.5s;
    -o-animation-duration: 13.5s;
    animation-duration: 13.5s;
}
```

Comment: What version of IE are you using?

Comment: @Dai, I am using IE8. But after seeing the answer below I will need to find an alternative.

Comment: IE8 does not support either CSS3 Animations nor CSS3 transforms, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using anything older than IE 10, keyframe animations are not going to work. See [Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/css-animation) for compatibility tables, and consider a JavaScript/jQuery alternative or polyfill if you need older browser support.

**EDIT**: It looks like some of your CSS (i.e., you `.gear` class) is missing the -ms prefix, which will give you somewhat broader compatibility.